# Error: no default constructor exists for class

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

I have a class derived from base class, and set constructors for each classes, but I keep getting error that I do not have any constructor for base class.

```
class Dog
    {
    protected:
    string name;
    int age;

    public:

    Dog(string dogsName, int dogsAge)
    {
        name = dogsName;
        age = dogsAge;
    }

    virtual void Bark()
    {
        cout << "Woof Woof I am a dog" << endl;
    }


class Huey: public Dog
{
public:

    Huey()
    {
        name = "goodboy";
        age = 13;
    }

     void Bark()
    {
    cout << "woof" << endl;
    }
}
```

Here I get an error on Huey() and it says " no default constructor exists for 'Dog'". But I think I have created a constructor for class Dog. Can you please explain why this code is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify any constructor of your own, the default constructor is not created anymore. However, you can just add it back.

```
class Dog
    {
    protected:
    string name;
    int age;

    public:

    Dog() = default;

    Dog(string dogsName, int dogsAge)
    {
        name = dogsName;
        age = dogsAge;
    }

    virtual void Bark()
    {
        cout << "Woof Woof I am a dog" << endl;
    }
};

class Huey: public Dog
{
public:

    Huey()
    {
        name = "goodboy";
        age = 13;
    }

     void Bark()
    {
    cout << "woof" << endl;
    }
};
```

EDIT: It seems like you want to call your custom `Dog` constructor from `Huey`. It is done like so

```
class Dog
    {
    protected:
    string name;
    int age;

    public:

    Dog(string dogsName, int dogsAge)
    {
        name = dogsName;
        age = dogsAge;
    }

    virtual void Bark()
    {
        cout << "Woof Woof I am a dog" << endl;
    }
};

class Huey: public Dog
{
public:

    Huey() : Dog("goodboy", 13) {}

    void Bark()
    {
    cout << "woof" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have a question... what about `Dog(string dogsName, int dogsAge)
    {
        name = dogsName;
        age = dogsAge;
    }`? Isn't this constructor also? I've learned this as overloaded constructor and I can use overloaded constructor when there is no default constructor....

Comment: Yes that is a constructor. You can instantiate an object using that constructor like this: `Dog d("Good boy", 2);`. In class `Huey` you can call `Dog::Dog(string, int)` by calling it in the initializer list: `Huey() : Dog("goodboy", 13) {}`. When you do not specify which constructor to use in the initializer list, it uses the default constructor. That is why you were getting an error because the default constructor was not being generated.

Comment: Again, sorry I'm very new at C++, but then why do I get an error of "No default constructor for class" and getting a hard error that stop me from running the code? Since I have an overloaded constructor which will replace the default constructor, shouldn't I get any error?

Comment: C++ is not smart enough to choose `Dog::Dog(string, int)`. You must manually specify to use it through the initializer list. C++ only knows the default constructor `Dog::Dog()` and your custom constructor does not match that function signature.

Comment: @M.M sorry, I'm not used to this yet so there are some typing error......

Comment: @BradyDean I think I have a better understanding now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constructor with no parameters and no implementation. As below:

```
 public:
    Dog() = default;
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain why I need to create a constructor with no parameters and no implementation? I've learned that once I have an overloaded constructor, I won't need default constructor. So I'm not understanding why I need to have that code........

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1) have a default constructor with no params. 
2) call the existing constructor you have in Dog from Huey ( this is the right thing in your case since Huey is a Dog after all). Huey is currently calling the default constructor of Dog since this isn’t defined and explicitly called.